# Limit log level from servlet that's written to Tomcat's catalina.out log level

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, logging, log4j

I have a web app WAR file which I can't modify. The code in the WAR file uses Log4j, and also contains log4j config file `logging.properties` that's loaded explicitly. This file sets `rootLogger` level to `DEBUG`. The web app is such that almost 50G of `DEBUG` logs are written to catalina.out on startup.

I need to limit the log level of messages coming from the servlet into catalina.out to `INFO`. How can I achieve this?

Tomcat version is 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I imagine just adding something like this to `logging.properties` should solve it.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=INFO
```

Although the [Apache Tomcat documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html) suggests this.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.session=ERROR
```

Comment: I'm still seeing all the DEBUG messates from the servlet. Do I need log4j.jar and commons-logging.jar in Tomcat's common/lib?

Comment: Saw your updated question with Tomcat Version. Try [this out](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html).  Provides detailed example of configuring log4j with Tomcat 5.5 and Catalina.

Comment: I tried this before, but it still writes DEBUG entries to catalina.out, even though in log4j config I have only one appender - tomcat.log

Comment: Are you sure the output is from log4j and not Tomcat's JULI? Could you update your question with your log4j properties?